How do I load openseamap as a source for a layer?
I am making an app in Android Studio where I want to implement the seamarks from OpenSeaMap as a layer for my Mapbox map. For testing, I’ve made a small program that just shows a map:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MapboxProjectTheme {
            CreateMap()
        }
    }
}

}
@Composable
fun CreateMap(){
MapboxOptions.accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFsaW1haGIiLCJhIjoiY2x1YjV6aWpoMDJuNzJrbnplcmZ2ZWZ5cSJ9.AydOxifMtLtcn9kEaxPG8A"

val mapView = MapView(LocalContext.current)

AndroidView({ mapView }) {
    val mapboxMap = it.mapboxMap
    mapboxMap.setCamera(CameraOptions.Builder()
        .center(Point.fromLngLat(10.20449, 59.74389))
        .zoom(10.0)
        .build())

    /*mapboxMap.loadStyle("mapbox://styles/halimahb/cluvbtwnb006s01qx3fix4xck") {

    }*/

    try {
        val rasterSource = RasterSource.Builder("openseamap-source")
            .url("https://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
            .tileSize(256)
            .build()

        mapboxMap.loadStyle("mapbox://styles/halimahb/cluvbtwnb006s01qx3fix4xck") {
            it.addSource(rasterSource)

            val rasterLayer = RasterLayer("openseamap-layer", "openseamap-source")
            //it.addLayer(rasterLayer)
            it.addLayerAbove(rasterLayer, "water")

            for (layer in it.styleLayers) {
                Log.d("Layers", "Layer ID: ${layer.id}")
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Mapbox", "Error adding source or layer: ${e.message}")
    }
}

}
When I run the app, I can see the map itself, but not the seamarks. I’ve added a log message that prints out all the layers in my style, and it’s obvious that the openseamap-layer has been added: “Layer ID: openseamap-layer”
However, I also get these two errors in my logcat:
[maps-android\Mbgl-StyleObserver]: OnMapLoadError: Source, message: Failed to load source: Invalid value. at offset 0, sourceID: openseamap-source, tileID: null
[maps-core]: {}[Style]: Failed to load source openseamap-source: Invalid value. at offset 0
I’ve pinged the server from my terminal to see if it the server was reachable, and it was, so I don’t think there are any server issues.
